# disappearing/distorted connector arrowheads when printing an HTML page with included SVG file created with Visio 2019/16 from second page onwards

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, microsoft-edge, visio

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an SVG file with a connector with arrowheads with MS-Visio 2016/2019 and the file is inserted into an HTML page with the  tag
2. The content of the HTML page (with included SVG) is displayed correctly in the browser itself (both Chrome and Edge).
3. But when this same HTML page is printed in the Chrome/Edge browser, the arrowheads do disappear (are distorted) in the print as soon the SVG file has been positioned on the 2nd page and/or further pages. The arrowheads are only printed correctly if the Visio SVG file is on the first page of the print of the HTML file.

Sample code for HTML file with SVG:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="SVGViewer1" data="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by Microsoft Visio, SVG Export svg_1.svg 1 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="8.26772in" height="11.6929in" viewBox="0 0 595.276 841.89" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st5">
    <title>9101im001</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        .st1 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.24}
        .st2 {fill:#000000;font-family:Verdana;font-size:0.666664em}
        .st3 {marker-end:url(#mrkr4-15);stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.24}
        .st4 {fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.08695652173913}
        .st5 {fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;font-size:12px;overflow:visible;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3}
    ]]>
    </style>

    <defs id="Markers">
        <g id="lend4">
            <path d="M 2 1 L 0 0 L 2 -1 L 2 1 " style="stroke:none"/>
        </g>
        <marker id="mrkr4-15" class="st4" refX="-23" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth" overflow="visible">
            <use xlink:href="#lend4" transform="scale(-11.5,-11.5) "/>
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <title>Page-1</title>
        <g id="shape16-1" transform="translate(127.559,-685.276)">
            <title>Process.16</title>
            <desc>ASSIGNED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="799.37" width="85.0394" height="42.5197" class="st1"/>
            <text x="20.93" y="823.03" class="st2">ASSIGNED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape39-4" transform="translate(127.559,-481.897)">
            <title>Process.39</title>
            <desc>PENDING REQUEST</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="3.21" y="830.12" class="st2">PENDING REQUEST</text>        </g>
        <g id="shape67-7" transform="translate(127.559,-765.354)">
            <title>Process.67</title>
            <desc>NEW</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="33.04" y="830.12" class="st2">NEW</text>       </g>
        <g id="shape94-10" transform="translate(162.992,-765.354)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.94</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 873.93" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape40-16" transform="translate(127.559,-553.465)">
            <title>Process.40</title>
            <desc>FIXED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="30.19" y="830.12" class="st2">FIXED</text>     </g>
        <g id="shape43-19" transform="translate(127.559,-368.511)">
            <title>Process.43</title>
            <desc>VERIFIED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="23.2" y="830.12" class="st2">VERIFIED</text>       </g>
        <g id="shape62-22" transform="translate(162.992,-553.465)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.62</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 879.59" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape63-27" transform="translate(162.992,-481.897)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.63</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 864.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape85-32" transform="translate(127.559,-425.204)">
            <title>Process.85</title>
            <desc>RETEST</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="27.02" y="830.12" class="st2">RETEST</text>        </g>
        <g id="shape112-35" transform="translate(127.559,-311.818)">
            <title>Process.112</title>
            <desc>CLOSED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="26.01" y="830.12" class="st2">CLOSED</text>        </g>
        <g id="shape33-38" transform="translate(162.992,-425.204)">
            <title>Dynamic connector</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 864.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape121-43" transform="translate(162.992,-368.511)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.121</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 864.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape122-48" transform="translate(14.1732,-425.204)">
            <title>Process.122</title>
            <desc>REOPENED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="20.52" y="830.12" class="st2">REOPENED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape123-51" transform="translate(127.559,-619.37)">
            <title>Process.123</title>
            <desc>OPEN</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="31.44" y="830.12" class="st2">OPEN</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape124-54" transform="translate(291.458,-659.055)">
            <title>Process.124</title>
            <desc>REJECTED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="21.99" y="830.12" class="st2">REJECTED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape125-57" transform="translate(291.458,-576.85)">
            <title>Process.125</title>
            <desc>DEFERRED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="20.91" y="830.12" class="st2">DEFERRED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape126-60" transform="translate(162.992,-685.276)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.126</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 873.93" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape127-65" transform="translate(162.992,-619.37)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.127</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 873.93" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape129-70" transform="translate(127.559,-432.291)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.129</title>
            <path d="M0 834.8 L-22.83 834.8" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape131-75" transform="translate(14.1732,-439.377)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.131</title>
            <path d="M0 841.89 L-6.38 841.89 L-6.38 647.72 L107.87 647.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape132-80" transform="translate(212.598,-633.543)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.132</title>
            <path d="M0 841.89 L121.38 841.89 L121.38 821.9" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape133-85" transform="translate(326.891,-637.795)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.133</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 868.97" class="st3"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg> </object>
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="SVGViewer1" data="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by Microsoft Visio, SVG Export svg_1.svg 1 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="8.26772in" height="11.6929in" viewBox="0 0 595.276 841.89" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st5">
    <title>9101im001</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        .st1 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.24}
        .st2 {fill:#000000;font-family:Verdana;font-size:0.666664em}
        .st3 {marker-end:url(#mrkr4-15);stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.24}
        .st4 {fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.08695652173913}
        .st5 {fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;font-size:12px;overflow:visible;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3}
    ]]>
    </style>

    <defs id="Markers">
        <g id="lend4">
            <path d="M 2 1 L 0 0 L 2 -1 L 2 1 " style="stroke:none"/>
        </g>
        <marker id="mrkr4-15" class="st4" refX="-23" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth" overflow="visible">
            <use xlink:href="#lend4" transform="scale(-11.5,-11.5) "/>
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <title>Page-1</title>
        <g id="shape16-1" transform="translate(127.559,-685.276)">
            <title>Process.16</title>
            <desc>ASSIGNED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="799.37" width="85.0394" height="42.5197" class="st1"/>
            <text x="20.93" y="823.03" class="st2">ASSIGNED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape39-4" transform="translate(127.559,-481.897)">
            <title>Process.39</title>
            <desc>PENDING REQUEST</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="3.21" y="830.12" class="st2">PENDING REQUEST</text>        </g>
        <g id="shape67-7" transform="translate(127.559,-765.354)">
            <title>Process.67</title>
            <desc>NEW</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="33.04" y="830.12" class="st2">NEW</text>       </g>
        <g id="shape94-10" transform="translate(162.992,-765.354)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.94</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 873.93" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape40-16" transform="translate(127.559,-553.465)">
            <title>Process.40</title>
            <desc>FIXED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="30.19" y="830.12" class="st2">FIXED</text>     </g>
        <g id="shape43-19" transform="translate(127.559,-368.511)">
            <title>Process.43</title>
            <desc>VERIFIED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="23.2" y="830.12" class="st2">VERIFIED</text>       </g>
        <g id="shape62-22" transform="translate(162.992,-553.465)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.62</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 879.59" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape63-27" transform="translate(162.992,-481.897)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.63</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 864.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape85-32" transform="translate(127.559,-425.204)">
            <title>Process.85</title>
            <desc>RETEST</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="27.02" y="830.12" class="st2">RETEST</text>        </g>
        <g id="shape112-35" transform="translate(127.559,-311.818)">
            <title>Process.112</title>
            <desc>CLOSED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="26.01" y="830.12" class="st2">CLOSED</text>        </g>
        <g id="shape33-38" transform="translate(162.992,-425.204)">
            <title>Dynamic connector</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 864.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape121-43" transform="translate(162.992,-368.511)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.121</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 864.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape122-48" transform="translate(14.1732,-425.204)">
            <title>Process.122</title>
            <desc>REOPENED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="20.52" y="830.12" class="st2">REOPENED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape123-51" transform="translate(127.559,-619.37)">
            <title>Process.123</title>
            <desc>OPEN</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="31.44" y="830.12" class="st2">OPEN</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape124-54" transform="translate(291.458,-659.055)">
            <title>Process.124</title>
            <desc>REJECTED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="21.99" y="830.12" class="st2">REJECTED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape125-57" transform="translate(291.458,-576.85)">
            <title>Process.125</title>
            <desc>DEFERRED</desc>
            <rect x="0" y="813.543" width="85.0394" height="28.3465" class="st1"/>
            <text x="20.91" y="830.12" class="st2">DEFERRED</text>      </g>
        <g id="shape126-60" transform="translate(162.992,-685.276)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.126</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 873.93" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape127-65" transform="translate(162.992,-619.37)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.127</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 873.93" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape129-70" transform="translate(127.559,-432.291)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.129</title>
            <path d="M0 834.8 L-22.83 834.8" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape131-75" transform="translate(14.1732,-439.377)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.131</title>
            <path d="M0 841.89 L-6.38 841.89 L-6.38 647.72 L107.87 647.72" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape132-80" transform="translate(212.598,-633.543)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.132</title>
            <path d="M0 841.89 L121.38 841.89 L121.38 821.9" class="st3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="shape133-85" transform="translate(326.891,-637.795)">
            <title>Dynamic connector.133</title>
            <path d="M7.09 841.89 L7.09 868.97" class="st3"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg> </object>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the print output of the sample code below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1TEG.jpg

This buggy behaviour is only with SVG files created with Visio and it is not present with SVG files created by similar diagram software (e.g. drawio - https://app.diagrams.net).

Looking for suggestions to resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully reproduced this issue on Chromium browsers (Chrome, Edge and Opera), but Firefox shows the marker correctly. Looks like a new issue related to "Printing to PDF" on Chromium browsers. I suggest [reporting this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) to the Chromium Dev Team.

Comment: Sure, will do that. Thanks, for verifying.

Comment: filed bug at Chromium dev
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1417631

Comment: Apparently, with me, Firefox (110.0 32-bit, WIN) print preview is extremely bad (not visible) 
Here is the link: https://imgur.com/a/XoKqfOQ

Comment: Filed a bug at Google Chrome too 
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/204159586?hl=en